# Background image in LI not showing up

Tags: class, html-lists, background-image, pixel

I'm wanting to put a background image from a class as a list item:

```
<ul>
<li> Stuff </li>
<li> More Stuff </li>
<li class= "horizdotted" </li>
</ul>
```

Here's the CSS

```
.horizdotted {
background-image: url("images/horizdotted.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;}
```

This doesn't work in any browser...it appears I have to have at least some info (other than a background image) in the LI. So, I made a png of a white pixel and tried another way:

```
<ul>
<li> Stuff </li>
<li> More Stuff </li>
<li class= "horizdotted"><img src="images/pixel.png" alt="teeny pixel" /> </li>
</ul>
```

Same CSS.  This worked in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE.  I can't, for the LIFE of me, get it to work in IE.  Please help if you can!!  Here's an image in Chrome of the second way (with the teeny pixel).
[Stuff, more stuff, dotted line in unordered list] http://www.flickr.com/photos/77703125@N07/8321020892/in/photostream/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set width and height in css

```
.horizdotted {
  background-image: url("images/horizdotted.png");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
 }
```

set this property according to your image size, that you want.

Comment: Oh man, you are awesome!!  That fixed it!!  I'm still not sure why I need the width and height, but it worked!

Answer (score 0):

[**jsFiddle for IE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8sBdj/)

You need to add content into your `li` so that it has something to show. Also, you have a syntax error for li in your Question. It is missing a closing bracket `>` symbol. You also have a blank space after the equal sign for class name too.

HTML:

```html
<ul>
  <li> Stuff </li>
  <li> More Stuff </li>
  <li class="horizdotted">Some stuff to view background.</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```css
.horizdotted {
  background-image:url(http://placehold.it/500x17/00ff00);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

---

[**jsFiddle for IE: No CSS**](http://jsfiddle.net/8sBdj/1/)

Also, since it's just a dashed line you want to show, then no CSS is necessary:

HTML:

```html
<ul>
  <li> Stuff </li>
  <li> More Stuff </li>
  <li>-----------------</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Adding a width and height of the background image in the CSS fixed the problem.  I only wanted the image, with no text or anything, so I added that little white pixel...which solved the problem in all browsers except IE.  Then when I added the width and height, I no longer needed even the little pixel.  Now the li class just has <li class="horizdotted"></li> with nothing inside...and it's viewing ok in the browsers.  yay!  Thanks for your help!